# how to use rlang::as_string() inside of a function?

Tags: r, rlang, nse

I'm writing a function where I supply a variable name as a symbol. At a different step in the function, I want to use the variable name as a string. Per the documentation, `rlang::as_string` "converts symbols to character strings."

Here is a basic example. This function returns a tibble with a column titled `mean`.

```
find_mean <- function(varname){
  tibble(mean = mean(pull(mtcars, {{varname}})))
> find_mean(qsec)
# A tibble: 1 × 1
   mean
  <dbl>
1  17.8
```

I want to add another column with the variable name as a string, like so:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 2
   mean variable
  <dbl> <chr>   
1  17.8 qsec
```

I thought this would work.

```
find_mean <- function(varname){
  tibble(mean = mean(pull(mtcars, {{varname}})),
         variable = rlang::as_string({{varname}}))
}
```

But it returns this error.

```
> find_mean(qsec)
 Error in ~qsec : object 'qsec' not found
```

I know I'm making some basic error regarding `rlang`'s nonstandard evaluation rules, but googling around hasn't helped me figure this out yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We may use `ensym` to convert to `sym`bol and then apply the `as_string`

```
find_mean <- function(varname){
  v1 <- rlang::as_string(rlang::ensym(varname))
  tibble(mean = mean(pull(mtcars, {{varname}})),
         variable = v1)
}
```

-testing

```
find_mean(qsec)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
   mean variable
  <dbl> <chr>   
1  17.8 qsec
```

---

This can be done in `base R` as well, i.e. with `deparse/substitute`

```
> find_mean <- function(varname) deparse(substitute(varname))
 
> find_mean(qsec)
[1] "qsec"
```

Comment: `ensym` - that's what I was missing! This also worked in my more complicated real use-case. Thanks a lot @akrun. Not the first time you've saved me great frustration.

Answer (score 2):

This could also be used. We use `enquo` to diffuse user-defined arguments and `!!` bang-bang operator to force-evaluate it. The difference between `ensym` and `enquo` is the first one returns a raw-expression whereas the latter returns a quosure, which is an expression bound to an environment. So in order to access the expression and turn it into string we need to use `rlang::get_expr` and wrap it with either `as_string` or `paste`:

```
library(rlang)

find_mean <- function(varname){
  tibble(mean = mean(pull(mtcars, !!enquo(varname))),
         variable = paste(get_expr(enquo(varname))))
}

# A tibble: 1 x 2
   mean variable
  <dbl> <chr>   
1  17.8 qsec
```